# Cannot create Postgresql database from ubuntu terminal

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, terminal, digital-ocean

I am trying to create Postgresql database from ubuntu terminal. I have DigitalOcean droplet and cluster where all my databases are. When I connect to the server via ssh@ip-address and try to create database using this command (instead of variables is real database configuration parameters and postgresql-client is installed):

```
createdb -h $PRODUCTION_DB_HOST -p $PRODUCTION_DB_PORT -U $PRODUCTION_DB_USER $NEW_DB_NAME
```

I'm getting this error:

> createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "159.89.235.94", user "doadmin", database "template1", SSL on

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, *...pg_hba.conf rejects*. You need to configure [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to allow a connection that matches those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "159.89.235.94", user "doadmin", database "template1", SSL on

You will need to connect from a host that is permitted in the `pg_hba.conf` file or edit the file to allow you to connect (and then reload the postgresql proceass).

Comment: how can I get to this file, it's a DigitalOcean cluster?

Comment: Reading the docs is a good start [Remote connection](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/postgresql/how-to/migrate/#allow-remote-connections).